# HTML5 video tag strange behavior on mobile CHROME but works on SAFARI

Tags: laravel, html5-video

I have a simple HTML 5 page that I'm testing for vídeo on TV accessing a web browser, but when i test it with CHROME on Android it doesn't work only in SAFARI.

After some searching, I already put these tags, and don't work too

**width="auto" height="400px" autoplay="" loop="" muted=""**

And this example in https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp, it works on my ANDROID I want to know WHY.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="pizza, delivery food, fast food, sushi, take away, Chinese, Italian food">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Digital Bravos | Soluções em Software">
    <title> Menu Digital TV </title>

    <!-- BASE CSS -->
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .video-container-menap video {
            position: initial;
            opacity: 1;
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>   

</head>

<body>

    <div class="video-container-menap">
        <div>
            <h1> RODAR VÍDEO </h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <video controls>
                <source src="url-for-video" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="url-for-video" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support HTML video.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what doesn't work? What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Just appear a play button, but when I press it, nothing is happening

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: I will try to console on my Android Phone, here see yourself: https://js-s6vp6y.stackblitz.io another link https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-s6vp6y?file=index.html

Comment: @James any resolution?

Comment: When I view that link in Chrome, it works fine for me.

Comment: From your mobile phone @James?

Answer (score 0):

The video is 156 MB, and is 3840x2160 - that's 4K (see the ffprobe:  https://www.streamclarity.com/probe?url=https://digitalbravos.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/menap/tenants/tenant7/video/nippon_tv1.mp4)

I'd recommend resizing this video to 1080p, or even 720p for your mobile users to have a chance to see it (and to not destroy their data plan).

I think the reason it is not appearing is that you are running some JS to hide the content until it appears on the screen... and perhaps it errors with such a huge file. Or perhaps the service worker cannot store a 150 MB video. Or it times out while downloading a 150 MB file...